# Complete GPS tracker working in any situation

Tags: android, gps

I am making an android application in which I want that whenever a user move 100 meters his/her location must be updated to the server. As per my requirement the tracking should be work at all the time and it must be never stops until user force stop the application.

- If GPS is not on it must take location with help of wifi/network/any other way and
- If GPS is on then it must use GPS to get the location.
  CPU must be allotted to the service.

My Tracking code is working fine but sometimes it stops or not updates the locations as per my requirement and not as fast as possible. I don't know why.

Like if I turn the connectivity off then after sometime its not working and onResume in MainActivity after login by a different user it also stops working.

I am calling this service in the MainActivity of my application. Also I am maintaining a serviceStatus variable for checking whether the service is currently running fine  or not than I don't want to make it start again and again. So if service was running I tried to skip the service starting and In onDestroy method of service I turned this variable off. But I don't know why it is not working. I am new to this type of work.
I am sharing the file uploaded on GoogleDrive:
[Tracking Service](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0Nh8wT0on4cWxuSVI5WUVpOFk/view?usp=sharing)